# Something strange with mybatis and isnull on BigDecimal with Sybase

Tags: java, mybatis, bigdecimal, isnull

Day ago I found something strange behavior in my code after adding new implementation of interface.

I see mybatis update return -1 always, and table not updated.

Log told me about some interesting behavior:

- Creating a new SqlSession
- SqlSession [...] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
- JDBC Connection [...] will not be managed by Spring
- ==>  Preparing: update Card set amount=isnull(?, amount), name=isnull(?, name), balanceTime=isnull(?, balanceTime) where number=? and clientId=?.
- ==> Parameters: 0.00(BigDecimal), Test Card(String), 2017-02-22 09:05:24.78(Timestamp), 0000000000000000(String), 111000(Long)
- Closing non transactional SqlSession [...]

After sending parameters to server nothing happened.
This happens after my DAO was refactored :

```
public class DBaseCard{
    private long id;
    private String number;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal amount; // was Double
    .....
}
```

In production I use Sybase IQ. For test I use H2 db and for it, all works fine.

If I change "amount" field type to Double, all works fine.

If I leave BigDecimal type and replace "amount=isnull(#{card.amount}, amount)" to "amount=#{card.amount}" or something like "amount=isnull(0.00, amount)" all works fine, and in log I see:

- ==> Parameters: 0.0(BigDecimal), ....
- <==    Updates: 1

Please, help me understand why this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be related to the type of the column in Sybase, H2 might have a more permissive behavior.

Check documentation on [Mybatis default type handlers](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers):

With BigDecimal:

> BigDecimalTypeHandler     java.math.**BigDecimal**    Any compatible
>   **NUMERIC or DECIMAL**

With Double:

> DoubleTypeHandler     java.lang.**Double, double**    Any compatible
>   **NUMERIC or DOUBLE**

It could come from *isnull* function. You can try to replace with *coalesce*.

Even though in the log, you see `0.00(BigDecimal)`, `0.00` is only the String representation of a Java BigDecimal and the value actually bound by the driver could be homogeneous to null for example `0`, and sometimes `0==null` whereas `0!==null`, that would explain why hard coded `0.00` works as expected.

Writing a stored procedure is option.

You may also consider using [Mybatis dynamic SQL](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) (**trim, where, set**) to build the SET, so that you don't have to rely on *isnull* anymore:

```
UPDATE
<set>
      <if test="amount!= null">amount=#{amount},</if>
      <if test="name!= null">name=#{name},</if>
      <if test="balanceTime!= null">balanceTime=#{balanceTime} </if>
</set>
WHERE number=#{number} AND clientId=#{clientId}
```

If you cannot guaranty there will be something in the SET (at least 1 not null parameter), the the `<set>` must contain (on last line) something neutral (no actual update), like: `id=id`.

Comment: Thanks for you help! You gave some good thought for my problem. So I create answer for my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the main case of my problem. After some time of viewing of mybatis sources, I understand, in my case there's nothing about Mybatis or SQL itself.  SQL request work's from ui client, and won't work from code. And I create a simple test:

```
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("conn_string", "login", "pass");

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update Card set amount=isnull(?, amount), name=isnull(?, name), balanceTime=isnull(?, balanceTime) where number=? and clientId=?");

    //ps.setDouble(1, 12.23);
    ps.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal("155.0"));
    ps.setString(2, "Test test");
    ps.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    ps.setString(4, "00000000000000");
    ps.setLong(5, 111010111L);

    LOG.info("execute update result: {}", ps.executeUpdate());

    conn.close();
```

I try some variants for 'conn_string': "**jdbc:jtds:sybase://...**" and "**jdbc:sybase:Tds://...**". And jConnect driver return **1** on update, instead of jTDS driver returns **0**.

Looks like a bug in jTDS driver?